# AngularJS Ng-repeat, create dynamic dom with expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is The problem i am trying solve. I would like to create a JS script that uses angular to dynamically create div elements while adding an additional expression eg {{levelone}}.

Here is an an example of what i am expecting the output to be if i know i have 5 iterations of Dom elements.

```
<div ng-switch-when="0">{{levelZero}}</div>
<div ng-switch-when="1">{{levelOneA}}{{levelOneB}}</div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">{{levelTwoA}}{{levelTwoB}}{{levelTwoC}}</div>
etc.....
```

So as you can see i am adding an expression on each time. I just dont know how i can keep adding them on via a repeat loop and then get them to compile correctly with AngularJS. I am trying to make my DOM as Dynamic as possible.

**EDIT**
Every time i loop 1 more i am adding an expression ->{{expression}} to the div with JS or angular. I am not hard coding the expression into each div as each div is also dynamically created. But with a twist i am adding that extra expression ie 3 expressions from the previous div and adding one more expression making four. see example below.

```
<div ng-switch-when="3"{{levelTwoA}}{{levelTwoB}}{{levelTwoC}}</div>
```

This one below is dynamically generated

```
<div ng-switch-when="4"{{levelTwoA}}{{levelTwoB}}{{levelTwoC}}{{THIS EXPRESSION IS GENERATED IN js AND ADDED & COMPILED}}</div>
```

Comment: Not really clear what data model vs expected results is.Are these actually nested in model and output?

Comment: even with your edits, it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish, or why.  At a minimum, you should probably show some sample data and your expected final output;  right now, you are just showing some random markup and suggesting parts of it are dynamic, but not *how* they are supposed to be dynamic (the function that is generating them) nor what they are supposed to dynamically become.

Comment: for what it's worth, saying that you want some angular code to be "dynamic" is one of the more misused statements.  It's **already** dynamic if it's a variable in the JS and an expression in the markup.... you can't make it any *more* dynamic.  Most questions suggesting they want their markup to be dynamic are either A: not understanding how angular works, or B: trying to use some other framework that angular doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM will be dynamic as long as your data bindings are.  I need more info (data model, expectations) to be more accurate but if you set up your data and bind it correctly, it should work.  for example if your data looked like this

```
var data = {
   "levelOne" : {},
   "levelTwo" : { 
       "elements" : ["<span id="firstEl"></span>, ...]
    },
   "levelThree" : {
       "elements" : ["<span id="firstEl"></span>, <span id="secondEl"></span>, ...]       
}
```

Then in your template do what @paulgoblin suggested.
}

Answer (score 0):

You could ng-repeat within each switch case. Eg.

```
<div ng-switch-when="0">
  <span>{{levelZero}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="1">
  <span ng-repeat="expression in levelOne">{{expression}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">
  <span ng-repeat="expression in levelTwo">{{expression}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want do this with scope function.

```
<div ng-switch="assignment.id">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">{{ getExpressions(assignment.id) }}</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">{{ getExpressions(assignment.id) }}</div>
</div>
```